# How to create macro variable from a column of dataset using data step not SQL?

Tags: sas, sas-macro, datastep

We can make macro variables via the SAS SQL Procedure, using the syntax

```
select var into :mvar
```

But I wonder if there's same way in data step.

I have a dataset.

```
A    B
===  ===
a1   b1
a2   b2
a3   b3
```

I can make a macro variable called `MA` with the below statement.

```
proc sql noprint;
   select "'"||A||"'" into :MA separated by ","
   from dataset;
quit;
```

How to do it in Data-step?

Comment: You can use the `quote` function, instead of all that bothersome concatenation, by the way, in either sql or data step.

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, creating your sample dataset:

```
data dataset;
infile datalines;
input A  $ B $;
datalines;
a1 b1
a2 b2
a3 b3
;
run;
```

The step below almost does what your `PROC SQL` does, using `CALL SYMPUT` to output a macro variable called `MA`:

```
data _NULL_;
  retain amac;
  length amac $35;
  set dataset;
  if _N_ = 1 then amac=a; else amac=cats(amac,',',a);
  put amac=;
  call symputx('MA',amac);
 run;

 %put &MA;
```

Comment: You could simplify it slightly by replacing the `if, then, else` statement with `call catx(',',amac,a);`

Comment: @user3457716: If this sufficiently answers your question, please consider marking it as accepted.